# How to disable obstacle avoidance in nav2 based on some condition?

Tags: navigation

I would like to disable obstacle avoidance in nav2 based on some condition while still continue avoiding obstacle based on some other condition. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the behavior tree to define custom logic. If the path is blocked, you can order your robot to halt and wait to proceed until its clear. This is one of the main benefits of Nav2 over other navigation alternative frameworks; you have full control over your autonomy logic within the behavior tree structure.

If you pair that with the RPP controller (which just naively follows the path) that should be a full solution that doesn't contain active collision avoidance.